# Rails removing url params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, tagging, acts-as-taggable-on

When I click on the tag links, it keeps getting added. Is there a way in rails so that when I click on the link again it removes the tag. Similar to check_boxes. Appreciate your help

```
<%= link_to tag.name, users_path(params.merge({tag:[params[:tag],tag.name]}))
```

Comment: Should it unlink if it's already linked?  Or do you want to change the url params.

Comment: Unlink I think, as I want to get rid of the param if i click at it again. For e.g. if i click on value2,  `/pages/product?param1=value1&param2=value2`  becomes `/pages/product?param1=value1`

Comment: Why not use a checkbox?

Comment: I want to search for tags as I click, instead of submitting a form

Comment: I don't understand what the desired behavior is.

Comment: @Ray: Can you provide more information about your models? What is a tag? How does it relate to user? What does your controller expect to do with params?